# Tableau: normalizing by number of records of other field

Tags: charts, field, visualization, tableau-api

I have two nominal (string) fields in Tableau, like so:

Field 1: A, A, A, B, B, C

Field 2: A, B, B, B, C, C

and want a chart to display the Number of Records of each A, B, and C from Field 1 on one axis, but divided by the Number of Records for the same A, B, or C from Field 2.

So in this example, I would basically be displaying the graph of this chart:

A - 3, B - 2/3, C - 1/2

This seems like it would be pretty simple to do in Tableau, but I can't seem to find out how. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, would you be able to provide a prototype of what you're looking for in Excel with the data structure?  Has anything in Tableau gotten close yet?